# Calling the methods of an object instantiated in one method, from another method

Tags: c#, .net, oop, methods, instantiation

I'm trying to call a method of an object that was instantiated in one method (`ObjectInstantiation()`), from another method (`Main()`). I boil down to this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void ObjectInstantiation()
        {
            TestClass testClass1 = new TestClass(6);
            TestClass testClass2 = new TestClass(7);
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            ObjectInstantiation();
            testClass1.PrintNumber();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class TestClass
    {
        int number;

        public TestClass(int i)
        {
            number = i;
        }

        public void PrintNumber()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
    }
}
```

This throws the error "The name 'testClass1' does not exist in the current context"
I understand that I could just instantiate them from within `Main()`, but I also need to access the object's methods from within a third method, separate from `ObjectInstantiation()` and `Main()`, so I run into the same issue again.

I should add that it's important that there are multiple instances of the class, as each one will store different values.

Comment: testClass1 and testClass2 go out of scope once the ObjectInstantiation() method returns.

Comment: you should research variable scope.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reference an object in any way, a reference to that object must be in scope. In this case, `testClass1` is a local variable and it is only in scope within the `ObjectInstantiation` method.

If you want to reference it in the `Main` method, you will need to make it a static member of the class:

```
private static TestClass testClass1;
private static TestClass testClass2;


public static void ObjectInstantiation()
{
    testClass1 = new TestClass(6);
    testClass2 = new TestClass(7);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void ObjectInstantiation()
{
    TestClass testClass1 = new TestClass(6);
    TestClass testClass2 = new TestClass(7);
}
```

this means that `testClass1` and `testClass2` are local variables and their scope is inside `ObjectInstantiation`. you can not access a variable outside it's scope.

you can declare your variables in a scope that is accessible to other methods you want.

```
static TestClass testClass1;
static TestClass testClass1;

public static void ObjectInstantiation()
{
    testClass1 = new TestClass(6);
    testClass2 = new TestClass(7);
}
```

and then use them in `Main`